# How to repeat list(of string) after randomize list index out of range

Tags: vb.net, exception

I'm a newbie programmer for VB.net

so I've been stuck in this code, this is for random name generator.

```html
Private Function RandomLname(ByRef ranLname As String) As String

        Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("[pathto file.txt]", Encoding.Default)
        Dim lines As New List(Of String)
        Dim rnd As New Random()
        Dim line As Integer
        While reader.Peek <> -1
            lines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
        End While

        line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 1)
        'the error shown in this line
        ranLname = lines(line)
        Return ranLname
        reader.Close()
        reader.Dispose()

    End Function
```

I keep getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception after few run, could anyone help me?
I need the script to read the list from the start again when it reach the list.count could anyone have idea?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `line = rnd.Next(lines.Count)`.

Comment: You have a major defect in your code there, in that you are closing the text file after the `Return` statement, i.e. you're not closing it at all.  You should open it with a `Using` statement and then it will be closed implicitly regardless of how the method ends.

Comment: i've already remove both reader.Close() and reader.Dispose() but it wont re-rear the list. also even when i remove (+ 1) the list wont produce any result after 60+ result written

Comment: `reader.Close()` and `reader.Dispose()` both do the same thing, you only need to call **one** of them. However they will never execute because the function exits at `Return`. Like jmcilhinney said you should wrap the `reader` in a [**`Using` block**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) instead and remove both the `Close()` and `Dispose()` calls.

Comment: i see,, btw how do you exclude/delete already used string from the list?

Comment: @jmcilhinney how do i do that?

Comment: What do you not understand about what you found when you searched the web for information on the `Using` statement?  Look first, ask questions later.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 1)
```

should be this:

```
line = rnd.Next(lines.Count)
```

The upper bound is exclusive when calling `Random.Next` and the maximum index in a collection is 1 less than the `Count`.

Comment: what can i do to read the list from start again when the upper bound reached? stuck on this. since the list i have contains 148 names, and i use random to get 2 names as couple. but the scrip run after 60+ couple when it should done in 74 couples. any idea?

Comment: If you have a new question to ask then ask a new question.  Don't piggyback it onto this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Function RandomLname() As String

    Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("[pathto file.txt]", Encoding.Default)
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim line As Integer
    While reader.Peek <> -1
        lines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    End While

    line = rnd.Next(lines.Count)
    Return lines(line)
    reader.Close()
    reader.Dispose()

End Function
```

Here's a simpler implementation for you:

```
Private rnd As New Random()
Private Function RandomLname() As String
    Return File.ReadAllLines("[pathto file.txt]").OrderBy(Function(x) rnd.Next()).FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```